# Boot Order not found if using efibootmgr to change boot order

Tags: boot

I am getting this error after i change the boot order using CLI `efibootmgr`

> System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults.
>
> Reset System

```
~# efibootmgr 
BootCurrent: 0001 Timeout: 1 seconds 
BootOrder: 0001,0009,000B,000C,0000 
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager 
Boot0001* ubuntu 
Boot0009* UEFI : USB : Generic-SD/MMC 1.00 : PART 0 : OS Bootloader 
Boot000B* UEFI : LAN : PXE IP4 Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-LM 
Boot000C* UEFI : LAN : PXE IP6 Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-LM
```

I change the boot order to USB

```
~# efibootmgr -o 0009
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0009
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0009* UEFI : USB : Generic-SD/MMC 1.00 : PART 0 : OS Bootloader
Boot000B* UEFI : LAN : PXE IP4 Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-LM
Boot000C* UEFI : LAN : PXE IP6 Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-LM
```

*** But this will NOT happen if I manually go into BIOS setting and move the boot priority.

*** No secure boot enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try listing the same number of boot options as there originally is:

```
...
BootOrder: 0001,0009,000B,000C,0000 
...
# efibootmgr -o 0009,0001,000B,000C,0000
```

Apparently your system firmware detects if you have 5 active boot targets (= with the asterisk after `BootNNNN`), but your `BootOrder` lists only one target, recognizes it as an invalid state, and solves it by completely deleting the `BootOrder` variable.

Or if you really want 0009 as the only active boot target, deactivate all the others:

```
# efibootmgr -A -b 0001
# efibootmgr -A -b 000B
# efibootmgr -A -b 000C
# efibootmgr -A -b 0000
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I am curious why this happened in a sudden because i have using the same command for a long time (`efibootmgr -o xxxx`) and it has no issue

Comment: Different firmware versions may implement the checks differently. Have you upgraded the system firmware ("flashed the BIOS") recently?

Comment: Yes, I did flash the f/w recently but I don't think it's the reason for having this issue. So I formatted that machine just now, and ran same `efibootmgr` command, surprisingly, it's working. To double confirm, I rollback to the old f/w, and ran the command, it works, and then, update to the newer f/w which seeing the issue, it also works. I'm thinking just something being messed up maybe and it gone after re-format